# Output from a Java agent in Lotus Notes to the client status bar?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

Does anybody know a way to get the behaviour of LotusScript `print` in a Lotus Notes Java agent, i.e. displaying the output on the client status bar?

Comment: I don't think you write to the Status Bar from a Java Agent. Is it critical that it goes in the Status Bar or is some other feedback OK.  You can open an AWT window from an agent and put what ever you like in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to natively print Java code to the status bar.

The only way you could do it, is to convert your code to Java classes, create a "print" method for the class, and then activate them in LotusScript using the JavaSession object in LotusScript. Once you have activated it in LotusScript, you can use the print method to assign it to a variable and then call the LotusScript "print" function. A roundabout way, but in essence you need to execute a "print" command within LotusScript

This should help:
http://www.codestore.net/help/help85_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/cfcde330df8ee09e852574cf006b67a7?OpenDocument